# How To move Quick View Before Add to Cart in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, frontend, catalog

I used the bss quick view and fist i want to need to remove th hover for quick view button and
second one i need to add quick view button before add to cart

here see

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add the below code to the XML file for the simple and configurable product:

Write your quick view element name in the element section.

```
<move element="{element name}" destination="product.info.addtocart.additional" />
```